# Count rows with columns all equal

Tags: r

I have a table Dice3 of 216 possible rolls of 3 dice, and I want to count the number of rows where the values of the first dice (Red3) = second dice (Green3) = third dice (White3) (i.e. first column = second column = third column)

I tried doing `nrow(subset(Dice3, Red3 == Green3 = White3))`, but doesn't work. Please help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have 3 6-sided dice:

```
set.seed(123)

Dice3 <- data.frame(
  red = sample(1:6, 100, replace = TRUE),
  green = sample(1:6, 100, replace = TRUE),
  white = sample(1:6, 100, replace = TRUE)
)
```

You can calculate the number of rows where the values for `red`, `green`, and `white` columns are the same. Use `apply` to go through each row in your data.frame, and determine if the number (or `length`) of `unique` values in that row is 1. If it is, then all 3 column values are the same.

```
sum(apply(Dice3, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == 1))
[1] 3
```

To check the 3 rows that have the same value, you can also `filter` your data.frame `rowwise` as follows with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

Dice3 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  filter(n_distinct(c_across(everything())) == 1)
```

**Output**

```
    red green white
  <int> <int> <int>
1     2     2     2
2     4     4     4
3     4     4     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting up the data:

```
mydf <- data.frame(x = runif(10, 1, 3) |> round(0), 
                   y = runif(10, 1, 3) |> round(0), 
                   z = runif(10, 1, 3) |> round(0))
mydf
   x y z
1  3 2 1
2  3 1 2
3  2 3 1
4  2 2 2
5  1 1 1
6  3 1 3
7  2 2 1
8  3 1 2
9  3 2 2
10 2 2 2
```

Creating a variable if the results in each column are the same or not:

```
mydf$equal <- ifelse(mydf$x == mydf$y & mydf$y == mydf$z, TRUE, FALSE)
```

Sum up how many times this happens:

```
sum(mydf$equal)
```

Proportionalize:

```
sum(mydf$equal) / nrow(mydf)
```